# Bind9 seems to route wildcard DNS even though they are not enabled?

Tags: ubuntu, domain-name-system, bind

For some reason bind9 seems to route wildcard DNS even though they are not defined anywhere?

Accessing `anyrandomstring.domain.com` routes to the domain even though they are not explicitly defined anywhere? Neither is wildcard defined anywhere in the files in `/var/cache/bind/`

I typed `sudo service bind9 reload` a couple of times now.

Any ideas?

Update: also tried using rndc 
Update2: ran `sudo service bind9 stop` and then accessed a random subdomain and it got routed

Answer (score 0):

It's not likely that bind will generate wildcard replies if it's not told explicitly to do so. My best guess is that you configuring one server (or one bind instance) and querying another one.

First make sure you really stopped bind - `sudo pgrep named` - should return nothing.
Then try local lookup - `dig @localhost anyrandomstring.example.com` if it generates wildcard reply, you definitely have wildcard in the zone file - recheck which named.conf actually used and check which zone file actually used.

If on the localhost you have no wildcard, and still have wildcard on other queries - look which nameservers answer for your domain - `dig example.com NS` and then query each of them `dig @nsN.example.com anyrandomstring.example.com`

This should let you find the source of problem.

Answer (score 0):

If your testing client is linux, check **/etc/resolv.conf** is pointing to the correct dns server. If you are testing from your dns box, the only dns server in that file should be **127.0.0.1**.